# Custom error page apache

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, custom-errors

I'm trying to setup a custom error page (reverse proxy is apache)

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

**Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**
```

But the error page isn't loaded if I stop my tomcat server for example (503 error)

And I receive the message above not my .HTML message

my config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin XXX
ServerName  XXX


# Possible values: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog XXX
CustomLog XXX
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location />
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass ajp://XXX:XXX/ disablereuse=on
</Location>
```

If I changed the line ErrorDocument to foo instead of /503.html I see foo so it looks like the .HTML isn't loaded by the config? Is there someone who can help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location `/` it's served by tomcat. This means that `/503.html` will be proxied via AJP to be processed by tomcat. If tomcat is down also `/503.html` page will be unavailable.
You need to add another `Location` stanza for error documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so you get something like this? 
<Location />
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass ajp://XXX:XXX/ disablereuse=on
</Location>
<Location /error>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument /var/www/html/error/503.html
</Location>

Comment: Yes, but pay attention of the order of each `Location` section: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location